# The proof about the countable additivity of the Lebesgue measure on measurable sets

Tags: real-analysis

Stein's proof goes as follows:
[image]

[image]

So my question is about the last equality. Here is what I thought. To get $m(E) = \sum_{i,j}m(E_{i,j})$ The latter sum has to be countable. The set $\{E_{i,j}\}$ is certainly countable since it is a countable union of countable sets. Then we can reindex $E_{i,j}$ to $A_i$ in some sort of order. Then it can be rewritten to a countable sum using $A_i$s. But how does one reason that $\sum_{i,j}m(E_{i,j})=\sum_{i}\sum_{j}m(E_{i,j})$?

$\sum_{i,j}m(E_{i,j})$ is not even rigorously defined in Stein's book. I definitely remember that there is some rigorous stuff behind 'double sums'.

Comment: You've left out some $m$s in your question.  Anyway, it's a general theorem that double sums of *nonnegative* terms can be freely interchanged.  It isn't hard to prove.  So you may define the double sum as either $\sum_i \sum_j m(E_{i,j})$ or $\sum_j \sum_i m(E_{i.j})$ if you like.  Another possible definition is the sup of $\sum_{(i,j) \in A} m(E_{i,j})$ taken over all finite subsets $A$ of $\mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N}$.  They're all equivalent when the terms are nonnegative.

Comment: But if you define it this way, how can you prove that $m(E) = \sum_{i,j}m(E_{i,j})$?